# String interpolation with a function

Tags: string, julia

I wonder why string interpolation in julia works for functions like `f1`, but failed for `findall` in the following example. Is there a way for me to use functions like `findall` with string interpolation?

```
f1 = function(x, y) x + y end
"1 + 4 = $(f1(1, 4))"

findall(r"a", "abca")

"x: $(findall(r\"a\", \"abca\"))"  # failed
```

[image]

I am using Julia 1.6.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In string interpolation inside `$(...)` you can write regular Julia code, there is no need to escape `"` etc as in your original example. Just plug in the exact same expression:

```
julia> findall(r"a", "abca")
2-element Vector{UnitRange{Int64}}:
 1:1
 4:4

julia> "x: $(findall(r"a", "abca"))"
"x: UnitRange{Int64}[1:1, 4:4]"
```

Comment: Wow, it's so simple.

Comment: This is still hard to understand for me. It seems that julia will do interpolation first when it encounter `$` symbol and then finish the construction of the string? If so, this cannot explain why the triple quotes works. Or because it automatically escapes double quotes inside `$()`?

Comment: There is no difference between single or triple quations here so I am not quite sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

This seems work after some trials. But I still do not why it fails with double quotes.

```
"""x: $(findall(r"a", "abca"))"""
```

[image]